# How to set Active class for Nav item in angular2

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, routes

I have some Code like below
Navigation =>

```
<nav class="navpart">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <div class="menus">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
   <li routerLinkActive="active" class="active"><a  routerLink="/home">Home</a></li>
                        <li routerLinkActive="active"><a routerLink="/product">Product</a></li>
                        <li routerLinkActive="active"><a routerLink="/service">Services</a></li>
                        <li routerLinkActive="active"><a routerLink="/about">About Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

App.module=>

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
      {path:"",component:HomeComponent},
      {path:"home",component:HomeComponent},
      {path:"product",component:ProductComponent},
      {path:"service",component:ServiceComponent},
      {path:"about",component:AboutComponent},
      {path:"**",component:NotFoundComponent}
    ])
```

i make the Home page as view for both localhost:4200 and also for localhost:4200/home
how can i set active class for Home routerLink when the url is like localhost:4200 and also for localhost:4200/home
Thanks in advance

Comment: An easy workaround would be changing your first Route to `{path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'}`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked.